# Scheme Function for Two Sublists

Tags: scheme, racket

Write the function (split x key) that returns a list containing two sublists based on x such that all elements in the first sublist are less than or equal to key and all elements in the second sublist are greater than key.

So, for example,

(split '(40 90 80 10 60 30 20 50 70) 40)

should return

((20 30 10 40) (70 50 60 80 90))

I know a helper function with extra list parameters can simplify the problem, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? SO is not a place to get your homework done for free!

Comment: You don't need a helper function (unless tail recursion is a requirement). Read about `let` and consider that you can recurse before making a decision about what to do with the result of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29):

```
(define (split lst num)
  (list (filter (lambda (e) (>= num e)) lst)
        (filter (lambda (e) (> e num)) lst)))

(split '(40 90 80 10 60 30 20 50 70) 40)
```

or [partition](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=partiti#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._partition%29%29):

```
(require racket/list)

(define (split2 lst num)
  (call-with-values
   (lambda ()
     (partition (lambda (e) (>= num e)) lst))
   list))

(split2 '(40 90 80 10 60 30 20 50 70) 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very constricted to try performing this with roll your own recursion without having a helper. You'd get lots of duplicated bad code.

Here is how to make a helper function:

```
(define (add-previous lst)
  (define (helper previous lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (+ previous (car lst))
              (helper (car lst) (cdr lst)))))
  (helper 0 lst))
```

This can be written easier with a named `let`:

```
(define (add-previous lst)
  (let helper ((previous 0) (lst lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (+ previous (car lst))
              (helper (car lst) (cdr lst))))))
```

For your problem you should add two result accumulator parameters in addition to the lst. You'll typically have 2 predicates and an alternative. One for the end of the list, where you use the 2 accumulated results, one for less or equal to key where you recurse and cons the current element to the accumulator for those and the alternative where you do the same except cons to the other result accumulator.